# Why is make not using this include path variable?

Tags: makefile

Here is my makefile

```
CC = clang
CXX = clang++
LD =
CFLAGS = -Wall
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11
LDLIBS = -lglfw3 -ldl -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lpthread -lXcursor

OBJ_DIR = bin
LIB_DIR =
INC_DIR = -I./include/ -I./src/
SRC_DIR = src

SOURCE = $(SRC_DIR)/gl3w.c $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/shader_util.cpp
OBJECTS = $(OBJ_DIR)/gl3w.o $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(SRC_DIR)/shader_util.o
EXECUTABLE = $(OBJ_DIR)/camo-generator

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_DIR) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/gl3w.o: $(SRC_DIR)/gl3w.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_DIR) -c -o $@ $<

... snip ...
```

And the terminal output

```
clang -Wall -I./include/ -I./src/ -c -o bin/gl3w.o src/gl3w.c
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -I./include/ -I./src/ -c -o bin/main.o src/main.cpp
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11   -c -o src/shader_util.o src/shader_util.cpp
src/shader_util.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'GL/gl3w.h' file not found
#include "GL/gl3w.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/shader_util.o] Error 1
```

Why is the `-I.include/ -I./src/` being dropped from the `shader_util.cpp` compile? I've tried making every file compile explicit and it still would 'forget' the proper include.

Comment: `$(SRC_DIR)/shader_util.o` -- seems like there's a typo here.

Comment: Ugh, I searched for about 5 minutes before I realized that SRC_DIR was in the objects variable... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in the line

```
OBJECTS = $(OBJ_DIR)/gl3w.o $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(SRC_DIR)/shader_util.o
                                                ^^^^^^^
```

Thanks to nobar for pointing that out.

Comment: Does it compile when you change that?

Comment: As for the reason why it failed in this particular way, I *guess* it didn't find the rule for making `$(SRC_DIR)/shader_util.o` (because there are rules only for files in the `$(OBJ_DIR)` directory), and so invoked the [implcit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) that failed.

Comment: Yes, it did compile as expected after the typo fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <GL/gl3w.h>
```

instead of

```
#include "GL/gl3w.h"
```

For `#include "GL/gl3w.h"` the preprocessor searches in the same directory as the file containing the directive. This method is normally used to include programmer-defined header files.

For `#include <GL/gl3w.h>` the preprocessor searches in an implementation dependent manner, normally in directories pre-designated by the compiler. This method is normally used to include standard library header files.

**shader_util.cpp** includes **gl3w.h** and **gl3w.h** belongs to a library that is not in your project, so the compiler says *file not found* when using `#include "GL/gl3w.h"`.